# Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ such that $\mathcal{M}(T) \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be an operator such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis of $V$ contains only real entries. Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then so is $\overline{\lambda}$. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the matrix of $T$ denoted by $A$. If $Ax= \lambda x$, then $A \overline{x}=\overline{Ax}=\overline{\lambda x}=\overline{\lambda} \overline{x}$

Comment: I'd write $A \overline{x}=\bar{A}\overline{x}=\overline{Ax}=\dots$

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial has real coefficients if $P(c)=0, \overline P(\overline c)=P(\overline c)=0$.

Comment: The question comes from exercise 16 in section 5.A in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right". Characteristics polynomials have not been introduced yet at the point I took the exercise from. Can the problem be tackled without?